# javascript regexp match anything between "{" and "}",but not between "@{" and "}"

Tags: javascript, regex

two strings as example:`"1@{loop1}dummy{s1}dummy"` and `"{loop1}dmy{s1}dmy"`,
my reg expression is: `/[^@]\{([\S\s][^\}@]*)\}/g`
I tested it at:https://regex101.com/r/tN8iH6/1

it matched "s1" in first string,"loop1","s1" in second string, this is exactly what i need,
but when code this in javascript:

```
var str1 = "1@{loop1}dummy{s1}dummy";
var str2 = "{loop1}dmy{s1}dmy";
var reg = /[^@]\{([\S\s][^\}@]*)\}/g
function getRegMatchedStrs(reg,str){
    rs = [];
    var regRs = 1;
    while(regRs){
        regRs = reg.exec(str);
        regRs && rs.push(regRs[1]);
    }
    return rs;
}

console.log(getRegMatchedStrs(reg,str1)); // get ["s1"] as expected
console.log(getRegMatchedStrs(reg,str2)); // get ["s1"] unexpected has no "loop1"
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: I forgot, not anything between "{" and "}", if the content between them contains "}" or "@",it will not  match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching a non-`@` character before the braces, so the braces can't be at the start of the string. Change `[^@]` to `(?:^|[^@])` (start of string or non-`@`).

EDIT: This does not solve the problem of being unable to match `bar` in `"{foo}{bar}"`. Man, not having lookbehind really sucks. Here's two workarounds:

```js
var str1 = "1@{loop1}dummy{s1}dummy";
var str2 = "{loop1}dmy{s1}dmy";
var str3 = "{loop1}{s1}dmy";

var reg1 = /{(.+?)}/g
function getRegMatchedStrs1(reg, str) {
    var rs = [];
    var regRs = true;
    while ((regRs = reg.exec(str))) {
        if (!regRs.index || str.charAt(regRs.index - 1) !== '@') {
            rs.push(regRs[1]);
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs1(reg1, str1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs1(reg1, str2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs1(reg1, str3)));
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var str1 = "1@{loop1}dummy{s1}dummy";
var str2 = "{loop1}dmy{s1}dmy";
var str3 = "{loop1}{s1}dmy";

var reg2 = /}(.+?){(?!@)/g
function getRegMatchedStrs2(reg, str) {
    var rs = [];
    var regRs = true;
    str = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    while ((regRs = reg.exec(str))) {
        rs.push(regRs[1].split('').reverse().join(''));
    }
    return rs;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs2(reg2, str1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs2(reg2, str2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRegMatchedStrs2(reg2, str3)));
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```